# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from local file

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL file which located in my server, I use this file a lot with SoapClient

```
$client = new \SoapClient(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::$url, array(
            'connection_timeout' => 180,
            'verifypeer'         => false,
            'verifyhost'         => false,
            'soap_version'       => SOAP_1_2,
            'stream_context'     => stream_context_create(['ssl' => [
                'verify_peer'       => FALSE,
                'verify_peer_name'  => FALSE,
                'allow_self_signed' => TRUE
            ]])
        ));
```

It works as expected but sometimes it still giving me this error

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '/var/www/public_html/laravel/app/Classes/orders_internal.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "/var/www/public_html/laravel/app/Classes/orders_internal.wsdl"

And it doesn't get back to work until I reboot the server!

Do you have any idea what am I missing?

Regards

Comment: I seem to be experiencing this issue, also using a local WSDL file. Did you manage to resolve it @Mohammed Taha ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too. I have a flow where I have to make 5 different calls to a soap api (in the same execution).

Only the last call was giving the error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from /var/www/html/SomFile.wsdl failed to load external entity.
```

I realized that just before the last call it was a logic to disable load external entities:

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(true);
```

Make sure there is no logic disabling the ability to load external entities in some part of the code.

It is important to notice that libxml_disable_entity_loader() will be deprecated:

**Warning**

```
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.
```